# Update a column in a database depending on the text in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update

I have a column of type int and a column of type varchar(255).

Is it possible for me to loop through every row in my database and check for a certain string in the varchar(255) column, if that string is found set a certain int for the row that its found on in my int column to a value of my choice?

So if on row 1 "abc" is found can I set the int column value to 2?

Any help would be appreciated,

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly loop through. This seems like a simple `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourIntCol = 2
WHERE YourOtherCol LIKE '%abc%'
```